# Почему слетел Apache?

Tags: apache, freebsd

Зашел на сервер, перезапустил Apache, все заработало. Но как узнать причину, почему это произошло? И может быть есть какой-то способ, что б он сам (ну или не сам) себя диагностировал?

freeBSD

лог за сегодня /var/log/httpd-error.log

```
[Sun Dec 11 05:19:27 2011] [warn] (itkmpm: pid=55490 uid=80, gid=80) itk_post_perdir_config(): setgid(0): Operation not permitted[Sun Dec 11 05:19:27 2011] [warn] Couldn't set uid/gid/priority, closing connection.[Sun Dec 11 09:42:00 2011] [error] [client 77.52.70.252] File does not exist: /usr/local/www/apache22/data/favicon.ico, referer: https://www.site.com/?req=ten&kat=[Sun Dec 11 09:57:00 2011] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down[Sun Dec 11 09:57:02 2011] [warn] RSA server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)[Sun Dec 11 09:57:02 2011] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `host.com' does NOT match server name!?[Sun Dec 11 09:57:02 2011] [warn] Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)[Sun Dec 11 09:57:03 2011] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...[Sun Dec 11 09:57:03 2011] [notice] Digest: done[Sun Dec 11 09:57:03 2011] [warn] RSA server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)[Sun Dec 11 09:57:03 2011] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `host.com' does NOT match server name!?[Sun Dec 11 09:57:03 2011] [warn] Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)[Sun Dec 11 09:57:03 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.21 (FreeBSD) DAV/2 PHP/5.2.17 mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/0.9.8n configured -- resuming normal operations[Sun Dec 11 16:47:37 2011] [error] [client 66.249.72.25] File does not exist: /usr/local/www/apache22/data/robots.txt
```

лог с начала дня и до момента когда уже заработало /var/log/httpd-access.log

```
212.113.хх.ххх - - [11/Dec/2011:05:19:26 +0200] "GET /manager/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1332212.113.хх.ххх - - [11/Dec/2011:05:19:29 +0200] "GET /webmail/ HTTP/1.1" 302 -77.52.хх.ххх - - [11/Dec/2011:09:41:59 +0200] "GET /?req=ten&kat=70&step=view&topic=141086 HTTP/1.1" 200 4477.52.хх.ххх - - [11/Dec/2011:09:42:00 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 20993.74.ххх.ххх - - [11/Dec/2011:09:59:20 +0200] "GET /manager/ HTTP/1.1" 200 174293.74.ххх.ххх - - [11/Dec/2011:09:59:21 +0200] "GET /manimg/sirius/local/ft-left.png HTTP/1.1" 200 342
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что произошло можно попробовать узнать из логов ошибок апача. Для FreeBSD - это `/var/log/httpd-error.log` (если не было изменено место по умолчанию). Кроме того, можно посмотреть и лог обращений `/var/log/httpd-access.log`. Нужно поискать по времени, что Apache писал и сопоставить с работой сайта.

Если на сайте выполняются приложения Django, или Zend, или еще что-нибудь, то у них есть свои логи, куда можно заглянуть.

Чтобы мониторить состояние сайта, можно подключать внешние службы, вроде [Яндекс.Метрики](http://metrika.yandex.ru/list/) или [pingdom](http://www.pingdom.com/), которые высылают уведомления при отсутствии ответа сервера в течение некоторого времени.

Comment: лог добавил в тему, я его сразу посмотрел, но ничего не понятно.еще стоит Zend

Comment: >`[Sun Dec 11 09:57:00 2011] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down`Этот перезапуска апача Ваш или провайдера?

Comment: я же написал - "Зашел на сервер, перезапустил Apache, все заработало."